# LINQ - Group by with SUM IF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Im trying to write in linq something which is easy (for me) in SQL. Any idea how to do something like this:

```sql
select Items.IdItem, 
       Items.Name, 
       count(1) as Quantity, 
       SUM(IF(State.IdStatus=1,1,0)) as Availible  
from Items 
       inner join State 
              on Items.IdItem=State.IdItem 
group by Items.IdItem
```

I wrote something like that:

```cs
var result = from items in _context.Items 
             join state in _context.State on items.IdItem equals State.IdItem 
             group items by { items.IdItem, items.Name } into g 
             select new { Name= g.Key.Name, IdItem=g.Key,IdItem, Quantity=g.Count(), Availible= ???? }
```

Any tips?

Comment: `g.Sum(i=>i.IdStatus == 1?1:0)` ?

Comment: You do a count of the group in your `Quantity` property. You could do a conditional sum of the `g` in a similar way. Edit: Pretty much what Selvin suggests ;-)

Comment: @Selvin I would suggest you posting an answer

Comment: It was my first idea, but i can only use fields from group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have set your relations in the database and navigational properties in your model (which is done by generators), then in Linq you seldom need joins (for tables that don't have a direct relation).

Second, you are not really after Sum() here, are you. Looking at your sum function and field name, it more looks like you are after "Is Available" check.

```
var result = from i in _context.Items
             group i by i.IdItem into g
             select new {
                  IdItem = g.Key,
                  Name = g.First().Name,
                  Quantity = g.Count(),
                  Available = g.Any(it => it.State.IdStatus == 1)
             };
```

EDIT: if your Sum was intentional, then you can replace the Available part by (it is a bit, right?):

```
Available = g.Sum(it => it.State.IdStatus)
```

EDIT: This one is based on your data/model and SQL at top:

```
var result = from i in _context.Items
             select new
             {
                 i.IdItem,
                 i.Name,
                 Quantity = i.States.Count(),
                 Available = i.States.Count(x => x.IdStatus == 1)
             };
```

Sample code and results:

```
string defaultConString = @"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=SampleDb;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

void Main()
{
    var _context = new MyContext(defaultConString);
    var result = from i in _context.Items
                 select new
                 {
                     i.IdItem,
                     i.Name,
                     Quantity = i.States.Count(),
                     Available = i.States.Count(x => x.IdStatus == 1)
                 };

    result.Dump(); // linqPad
}


public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public MyContext(string connectionString)
     : base(connectionString)
  { }
  public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
  public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
}

[Table("Items")]
public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.States = new List<State>();
        OnCreated();
    }
    [Key]
    public virtual int IdItem { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual System.DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }
    public virtual System.DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<State> States { get; set; }
    partial void OnCreated();
}

[Table("States")]
public partial class State
{
    public State()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
    [Key]
    public virtual int IdState { get; set; }
    public virtual string SmId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdItem { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    partial void OnCreated();
}
```

Result:

```
IdItem Name   Quantity Available
   1   Test01     3       2
   2   Test02     2       1
   3   Test03     1       0
```

Comment: You're right. I dont need joins, thx. I try your solution and the problem is that relation between Items and State is one to many so i cant access it like that: 
`Available = g.Sum(it => it.State.IdStatus)`
Any tips?

Comment: @yarnsik, Which one is the many side? Would you give some sample data to understand.

Comment: Here are classes and sample data: https://pastebin.com/sgkhdEfv As you can see i used SUM and IF in query cause IdStatus can have different values not only 0 or 1. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @yarnsik, seeing the data and model helped a lot. There wasn't a need for grouping at all. I am now editing it to match to your requirement (the SQL you gave - after corrected).

Comment: I tested your solution and correctly counts the data, but it returns as many rows as is in the table States. So for sample data result had 6 rows instead 3. The second problem is that generated SQL is terrible: `SELECT baz.IdItem,baz.Name, (SELECT Count(*)
FROM States u
WHERE baz.IdItem = u.IdItem) AS Quantity, (SELECT Count(*)
FROM States x
WHERE (x.IdStatus = 1) AND (baz.IdItem = x.IdItem)) AS Available
FROM Items baz`

Comment: @yarnsik, it returns the same result as your SQL for me (corrected version of SQL) - just 3 rows. I don't understand why you would think generated SQL is terrible.